# how get all related objects

Tags: python, django, django-models, many-to-many

I have some models:

```
Tag(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()
Tag2(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()

Blog(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()
    tag = models.ManyToMany(Tag)
    tag2 = models.ManyToMany(Tag2)

Author(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()
    tag = models.ManyToManyField(Tag)
    tag2 = models.ManyToManyField(Tag2)

SomeOtherModel1(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()
    tag = models.ManyToManyField(Tag)
    tag2 = models.ManyToManyField(Tag2)

SomeOtherModel2(models.Model):
    someothermodel1 = models.ManyToManyField(SomeOtherModel1)
    tag2 = models.ManyToManyField(Tag2)

Post(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()
    tag = models.ManyToMany(Tag)
    tag2 = models.ManyToMany(Tag2)
    author = models.ManyToMany(Author)
    blog = models.ForeignKey(Blog)
    someothermodel = models.ForeignKeyField(SomeOtherModel2)
```

I need to collect all tags and tag2s (from blog, author and all another related objects) for `Post` element. In future I'm planing to add other models

How to make it?

My current solution is:

```
AbstractModel(models.Model)
    class Meta:
        abstract = True
    def tags(self, add_self=True):
        try: result = self.tag.all() if add_self else Tag.objects.none()
        except: result = Tag.objects.none()
        for fieldname in self._meta.get_all_field_names():
            try: result |= reduce(or_, [child.tags() for child in self._meta.get_field(fieldname).value_from_object(self)])
            except: pass
        return result
    def tag2s(self, add_self=True):
        try: result = self.tag2.all() if add_self else Tag2.objects.none()
        except: result = Tag2.objects.none()
        for fieldname in self._meta.get_all_field_names():
            try: result |= reduce(or_, [child.tag2s() for child in self._meta.get_field(fieldname).value_from_object(self)])
            except: pass
        return result

Author(AbstractModel)
    ...
SomeOtherModel1(AbstractModel)
    ...
SomeOtherModel2(AbstractModel)
    ...
Post(AbstractModel)
    ...
```

I think this solution is ugly. How to make it beautiful?
How to make it without using additional functions (tag2s, tag3s, ... etc)
Like this:

```
class AbstractModel(models.Model):
    def getRelatedObjects(fieldname='tag', add_self=True):
```

Comment: What properties does a non-ugly solution have?

Comment: @pts I want to get related fields by fieldname. Like this:

`def getRelatedObjects(fieldname='tag', add_self=True):`

Comment: You can use getattr for that, e.g. `child.tags()` is equivalent of `getattr(child, 'tags'`, and `Tag` is equivalent to `globals()['Tag']`. You can compute `tags' and `Tag` from `fieldname`.